# vim is inserting Q when I hit F2

Tags: vim

At some point last night my VIM started inserting Q when I hit F2. And other letters when I hit F3, F4 etc.

I had these keys mapped to other commands, but I did not understand why it's not working.

At some point I commented out everything in my .vimrc and tried again - and it's still inserting Q. Does anyone know what it could be caused by? Google doesn't help.

It's Ubuntu, console VIM.

Comment: Does your keyboard have some kind of `f-lock` button?

Comment: It also inserts D when I hit Left key. And Delete doesn't work. Really weird.

Comment: Is this only in vim? What about in a terminal etc?

Comment: F-lock: I don't know - does it? Here's my keyboard:  http://cdn.skatter.com/blob/files/2008/08/acer-aspire-one-keyboard.jpg

Comment: In other programs: Don't think so. In VIM when I hit Delete - it upcaces the selected letter O_o. I definitely don't have this behaviour say in Gedit or Skype.

Comment: I do have some plugins, but they were there for a month now, and problem occured only yesterday.

Comment: Same problem in VI (not VIM)

Comment: I removed all plugins - problem is still there.

Comment: Sounds like youre in compatible mode. (No idea why though...)

Comment: How do I fix it? This didn't help: http://superuser.com/questions/543317/what-is-compatible-mode-in-vim

Comment: Looks like `set nocompatible` helped. Thx.

Comment: You know what, it didn't help. Same thing again.

Comment: I'll probably just reinstall Ubuntu whenever I have time. It's kinda old anyway.

Comment: what is your console ? what do you have in your $TERM environment variable ? did you update/upgrade other packages recently ? Does the Fn works for a simple function ? what are your vim options ? and vim version ?

Comment: Are you in normal mode or insert mode when you hit F2?  Which version is your vim ? Type `:map` to see your map-keys and find what F2 is mapped to.

Answer (score 4):

I meet the same problem.

The reason is that terminal Vim has many ordinary keys that can't be recognized.

F1  \033OP

F2  \033OQ

F3  \033OR

F4  \033OS

When you press the key, these letters will be sent to the terminal, where \033 represent `esc`. So that the VIM will insert Q or other letter.

One way is to map these keys explicitly in your .vimrc file.

```
map <Esc>OP <F1>
map <Esc>OQ <F2>
map <Esc>OR <F3>
map <Esc>OS <F4>
map <Esc>[16~ <F5>
map <Esc>[17~ <F6>
map <Esc>[18~ <F7>
map <Esc>[19~ <F8>
map <Esc>[20~ <F9>
map <Esc>[21~ <F10>
map <Esc>[23~ <F11>
map <Esc>[24~ <F12>
```

Another way is to install gvim or macvim. There is no problems with mapping with F2, as I tried.